# Preload CCAction?

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, lag, ccaction

I notice in my Cocos2D app that whenever I load a specific CCAction for the first time there a slight lag (maybe like 0.3 seconds) however this does not occur the second time. This is the most noticeable with the CCShake action: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/20327

There are no leaks anywhere and I preload assets so it can't be anything related to those two things. Anyway is it possible to preload a CCAction so that there is no lag the first time I call it? If not, what workarounds are there to achieve something similar to this so that there isn't any lag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the CCAnimationCache http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.0.0/interface_c_c_animation_cache.html